# Extract phone number from noised string

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, database, data-cleaning

I have a column in a table that contains random data along with phone numbers in different formats. The column may contain

- Name
- Phone
- Email
- HTML tags
- Addresses (with numbers)

Examples:

```
1) Call back from +79005346546, Conversation started<br>Phone: +79005346546<br>Called twice Came from google.com<br>IP: 77.106.46.202 the web page address is xxx.com utm_medium: cpc<br>utm_campaign: 32587871<br>utm_content: 5283041 79005346546 
2) John Smith
3) xxx@yyy.com
4) John Smith 8 999 888 77 77
```

How a phone number is written is also depends. It may be like `8 927 410 00 22, 8(927)410-00-22, +7(927)410-00-22, +7 (927) 410-00-22, (927)410 00 22, 927 410 00 22, 9(2741) 0 0 0-22` and so on

The common rule here is that the phone number format contains 10-11 digits.

My best guess is to use regular expressions and firstly remove email addresses (since they can contain phone numbers in them like 79990001122@gmail.com) from the string and then use some regular expression to extract phone based on knowing it's 10 or 11 digits in row delimited with characters like `,(,),+,-` and so on (I don't think someone would use `.` as phone digit delimiter so we don't want to think of IP Addresses like `77.106.46.202` in the first sample).

So the question is how to get phone numbers from these values.

The final values I want to get from the three examples above are:

```
1) 79005346546 79005346546 79005346546 
2) 
3) 
4) 89998887777
```

The server is `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) Standard Edition (64-bit)`

Comment: Phone numbers are a contiguous stream of integers disregarding any ` `, `(`, or `)` between them. One way to go is to clear any of these characters that lies between integers then extract any string containing only numbers that is at least say 6 characters long.

Comment: Regex would be the ideal tool for this, but SQL Server does not have regex support.

Comment: I would suggest that instead of searching from raw data you should do some polishing to filter out email, IP address and other unwanted string of numbers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I search a bit and found that we can add regexp support for SQL Server using this https://github.com/DevNambi/sql-server-regex/blob/master/examples/replace.md

Comment: @Rahul I've updated my question. I forgot to mention that these rows can contain addresses which as we all know can contain numbers

Comment: Are you basically asking for regex to extract from 10 to 11 consequent digits with some allowed characters in between and not ending with @ sing? Or something else?

Comment: You can have regex running in just a few minutes, there are good CLRs that ship with MDS/DQS. You don't even need MDS or DQS installed. I posted about this like 8 years ago here: http://xmlsqlninja.blogspot.com/p/code-to-create-microsoftmasterdataservi.html and here: http://xmlsqlninja.blogspot.com/2013/05/mdqregex-clr-functions-part-2.html. 

All that said, except for VERY small set of exceptions - regex can't touch ngrams8k from a performance standpoint which is why I posted a ngrams8k - based solution below.

Comment: I think in such requirement CLR UDF is the choice.There are lot of string and regex manipulation  involve.It will be effecient also.Don't waste your time in trying to find single regex to handle every thing.You have to create Regex for every single Case.It is interesting and lengthy question,when free I would love to try it.

Comment: In my opinion, T-SQL is not the best tool to do this kind of thing. I would do this kind of data extraction / cleanup in a language like C# and then pass the clean data to a Stored Procedure. C# (or similar languages) have full regex support and any other manipulation you may need.

Comment: @KumarHarsh  "[CLR/Regex] will be effecient also." Not nearly as efficient as NGrams8K, not even close. I updated my code below to include a 1,000,000 Row performance test. The NGrams Solution is roughly 24 Times Faster.

Comment: @Gert-Jan see my updated post below - there is no beating ngrams8k for this type of thing. I have been saying it for a years and have yet to be proven wrong.

Comment: @AlanBurstein,Thanks a lot.I read and test your script

Answer (score 11):

### UPDATED (20200226)

There were a couple comments that a CLR/regex solution could be faster than the ngram8k solution I posted. I've heard this for six years but every single time, without exception, the test harness tells a different story. I already posted in the earlier comments instructions to get the Microsoft© MDQ family of CLR Regex running in just a few minutes. They were developed, tested and tuned by Microsoft and ship with Master Data Services/Data Quality Services. I've used them for years, they're good.

### RegexReplace/RegexSplit vs PatExtract8k/DigitsOnlyEE: 1,000,000 rows

Obviously you don't want functions in your `WHERE`clause but, since my Regex is rusty AF, I needed to. To level the playing field I did the same with DigitsOnlyEE in the N-Gram solution's WHERE clause.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE    WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

DECLARE
  @newData BIT            = 0,
  @string  VARCHAR(8000)  = '1) Call back from +79005346546, Conversation started<br>Phone: +79005346546<br>Called twice Came from google.com<br>IP: 77.106.46.202 the web page address is xxx.com utm_medium: cpc<br>utm_campaign: 32587871<br>utm_content: 5283041 79005346546 ',
  @pattern VARCHAR(50)    = '[^0-9()+.-]',
  @srchLen INT            = 11;

IF @newData = 1
BEGIN
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#strings','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #strings;

  SELECT 
    StringId = IDENTITY(INT,1,1),
    String   = REPLICATE(@string,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%3)+1)
  INTO   #strings
  FROM   dbo.rangeAB(1,1000000,1,1) AS r;
END

PRINT CHAR(10)+'Regex/CLR version Serial'+CHAR(10)+REPLICATE('-',90);
SELECT regex.NewString
FROM   #strings AS s
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT STRING_AGG(clr.RegexReplace(f.Token,'[^0-9]','',0),' ')
  FROM   clr.RegexSplit(s.string,@pattern,N'[0-9()+.-]',0) AS f
  WHERE  f.IsValid = 1
  AND    LEN(clr.RegexReplace(f.Token,'[^0-9]','',0)) = @srchLen
) AS regex(NewString);

PRINT CHAR(10)+'NGrams version Serial'+CHAR(10)+REPLICATE('-',90);
SELECT ngramsStuff.NewString
FROM   #strings AS s
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT      STRING_AGG(ee.digitsOnly,' ')
  FROM        samd.patExtract8K(@string,@pattern) AS pe
  CROSS APPLY samd.digitsOnlyEE(pe.item)          AS ee
  WHERE       LEN(ee.digitsOnly) = @srchLen
) AS ngramsStuff(NewString)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
GO
```

**Test Results**

```
Regex/CLR version Serial
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 19918 ms,  elapsed time = 12355 ms.

NGrams version Serial
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 844 ms,  elapsed time = 971 ms.
```

NGrams8k is very fast, does not require you to compile a new assembly, learn a new programming language, Enable CLR functions, etc... No issues with garbage collection. Even the CLR N-GRAMs function that ships with MDS/DQS can't touch NGrams8k for performance (see the comments under my article).

### END OF UPDATE

---

First grab a copy of [ngrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) and use it to build PatExtract8k (DDL below at the bottom of this post.) Next a quick warm-up:

```
DECLARE
  @string  VARCHAR(8000)  = 'Call me later at 222-3333 or tomorrow at 312.555.2222, 
                             (313)555-6789, or at 1+800-555-4444 before noon. Thanks!',
  @pattern VARCHAR(50)    = '%[^0-9()+.-]%';


SELECT pe.itemNumber, pe.itemIndex, pe.itemLength, pe.item
FROM   samd.patExtract8K(@string,@pattern) AS pe
WHERE  pe.itemLength > 1;
```

**Returns:**

```
ItemNumber  ItemIndex   ItemLength  Item
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------
1           18          8           222-3333
2           42          12          312.555.2222
3           91          13          (313)555-6789
4           112         14          1+800-555-4444
```

Note that the function returns the matched pattern, position in the string, Item Length *and* the item. The first three attributes can be leveraged for further processing which brings us to your post. Note my comments:

```
-- First for some easily consumable sample data. 
DECLARE @things TABLE (StringId INT IDENTITY, String VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT @things (String)
VALUES
('Call back from +79005346546, Conversation started<br>Phone: +79005346546<br>Called twice Came from google.com<br>IP: 77.106.46.202 the web page address is xxx.com utm_medium: cpc<br>utm_campaign: 32587871<br>utm_content: 5283041 79005346546 '),
('John Smith'),
('xxx@yyy.com'),
('John Smith 8 999 888 77 77');

DECLARE @SrchLen INT = 11;

SELECT
  StringId   = t.StringId, 
  ItemIndex  = pe.itemIndex,
  ItemLength = @SrchLen,
  Item       = i2.Item
FROM        @things AS t
CROSS APPLY samd.patExtract8K(t.String,'[^0-9 ]')                        AS pe
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',@SrchLen), pe.item))) AS i(Idx)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(pe.Item,NULLIF(i.Idx,0),11)))              AS ns(NewString)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(ns.NewString, REPLACE(pe.item,' ',''))))      AS i2(Item)
WHERE       pe.itemLength >= @SrchLen;
```

**Returns:**

```
StringId    ItemIndex            ItemLength  Item
----------- -------------------- ----------- -----------
1           17                   11          79005346546
1           62                   11          79005346546
1           221                  11          79005346546
4           11                   11          89998887777
```

Next we can handle *outer* rows like so and row-to-column concatenation like this:

```
WITH t AS
(
  SELECT      i2.Item, t.StringId
  FROM        @things AS t
  CROSS APPLY samd.patExtract8K(t.String,'[^0-9 ]')                        AS pe
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',@SrchLen), pe.item))) AS i(Idx)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(pe.Item,NULLIF(i.Idx,0),11)))              AS ns(NewString)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(ns.NewString, REPLACE(pe.item,' ',''))))      AS i2(Item)
  WHERE       pe.itemLength >= @SrchLen
)
SELECT 
  StringId  = t2.StringId,
  NewString = ISNULL((
    SELECT t.item+' '
    FROM   t
    WHERE  t.StringId = t2.StringId
    FOR XML PATH('')),'')
FROM      @things AS t2
LEFT JOIN t       AS t1 ON t2.StringId = t1.StringId
GROUP BY  t2.StringId;
```

**Returns:**

```
StringId  NewString
--------- --------------------------------------
1         79005346546 79005346546 79005346546 
2         
3         
4         89998887777
```

I wish I had a little more time for additional details but this took a little longer then planned. Any questions welcome.

**Patextract:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION samd.patExtract8K
(
  @string  VARCHAR(8000),
  @pattern VARCHAR(50)
)
/*****************************************************************************************
[Description]:
 This can be considered a T-SQL inline table valued function (iTVF) equivalent of 
 Microsoft's mdq.RegexExtract except that:

 1. It includes each matching substring's position in the string

 2. It accepts varchar(8000) instead of nvarchar(4000) for the input string, varchar(50)
    instead of nvarchar(4000) for the pattern

 3. The mask parameter is not required and therefore does not exist.

 4. You have specify what text we're searching for as an exclusion; e.g. for numeric 
    characters you should search for '[^0-9]' instead of '[0-9]'. 

 5. There is is no parameter for naming a "capture group". Using the variable below, both 
    the following queries will return the same result:

     DECLARE @string nvarchar(4000) = N'123 Main Street';

   SELECT item FROM samd.patExtract8K(@string, '[^0-9]');
   SELECT clr.RegexExtract(@string, N'(?<number>(\d+))(?<street>(.*))', N'number', 1);

 Alternatively, you can think of patExtract8K as Chris Morris' PatternSplitCM (found here:
 http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/) but only returns the
 rows where [matched]=0. The key benefit of is that it performs substantially better 
 because you are only returning the number of rows required instead of returning twice as
 many rows then filtering out half of them.  Furthermore, because we're 

 The following two sets of queries return the same result:

 DECLARE @string varchar(100) = 'xx123xx555xx999';
 BEGIN
 -- QUERY #1
 -- patExtract8K
   SELECT ps.itemNumber, ps.item 
   FROM samd.patExtract8K(@string, '[^0-9]') ps;

   -- patternSplitCM   
   SELECT itemNumber = row_number() over (order by ps.itemNumber), ps.item 
   FROM dbo.patternSplitCM(@string, '[^0-9]') ps
   WHERE [matched] = 0;

 -- QUERY #2
   SELECT ps.itemNumber, ps.item 
   FROM samd.patExtract8K(@string, '[0-9]') ps;

   SELECT itemNumber = row_number() over (order by itemNumber), item 
   FROM dbo.patternSplitCM(@string, '[0-9]')
   WHERE [matched] = 0;
 END;

[Compatibility]:
 SQL Server 2008+

[Syntax]:
--===== Autonomous
 SELECT pe.ItemNumber, pe.ItemIndex, pe.ItemLength, pe.Item
 FROM samd.patExtract8K(@string,@pattern) pe;

--===== Against a table using APPLY
 SELECT t.someString, pe.ItemIndex, pe.ItemLength, pe.Item
 FROM samd.SomeTable t
 CROSS APPLY samd.patExtract8K(t.someString, @pattern) pe;

[Parameters]:
 @string        = varchar(8000); the input string
 @searchString  = varchar(50); pattern to search for

[Returns]:
 itemNumber = bigint; the instance or ordinal position of the matched substring
 itemIndex  = bigint; the location of the matched substring inside the input string
 itemLength = int; the length of the matched substring
 item       = varchar(8000); the returned text

[Developer Notes]:
 1. Requires NGrams8k

 2. patExtract8K does not return any rows on NULL or empty strings. Consider using 
    OUTER APPLY or append the function with the code below to force the function to return 
    a row on emply or NULL inputs:

    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 0, NULL, @string WHERE nullif(@string,'') IS NULL;

 3. patExtract8K is not case sensitive; use a case sensitive collation for 
    case-sensitive comparisons

 4. patExtract8K is deterministic. For more about deterministic functions see:
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx

 5. patExtract8K performs substantially better with a parallel execution plan, often
    2-3 times faster. For queries that leverage patextract8K that are not getting a 
    parallel exeution plan you should consider performance testing using Traceflag 8649 
    in Development environments and Adam Machanic's make_parallel in production. 

[Examples]:
--===== (1) Basic extact all groups of numbers:
  WITH temp(id, txt) as
 (
   SELECT * FROM (values
   (1, 'hello 123 fff 1234567 and today;""o999999999 tester 44444444444444 done'),
   (2, 'syat 123 ff tyui( 1234567 and today 999999999 tester 777777 done'),
   (3, '&**OOOOO=+ + + // ==?76543// and today !!222222\\\tester{}))22222444 done'))t(x,xx)
 )
 SELECT
   [temp.id] = t.id,
   pe.itemNumber,
   pe.itemIndex,
   pe.itemLength,
   pe.item
 FROM        temp AS t
 CROSS APPLY samd.patExtract8K(t.txt, '[^0-9]') AS pe;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Revision History:
 Rev 00 - 20170801 - Initial Development - Alan Burstein
 Rev 01 - 20180619 - Complete re-write   - Alan Burstein
*****************************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT itemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f.position),
       itemIndex  = f.position,
       itemLength = itemLen.l,
       item       = SUBSTRING(f.token, 1, itemLen.l)
FROM
(
 SELECT ng.position, SUBSTRING(@string,ng.position,DATALENGTH(@string))
 FROM   samd.NGrams8k(@string, 1) AS ng
 WHERE  PATINDEX(@pattern, ng.token) <  --<< this token does NOT match the pattern
        ABS(SIGN(ng.position-1)-1) +    --<< are you the first row?  OR
        PATINDEX(@pattern,SUBSTRING(@string,ng.position-1,1)) --<< always 0 for 1st row
) AS f(position, token)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%'+@pattern+'%',f.token),0),
  DATALENGTH(@string)+2-f.position)-1)) AS itemLen(l);
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

The following isn't a direct answer to the question but shows how it can be done in PostgresSQL, which has a mature regular expression replace function. Would expect the solution might be adaptable to SQL Server using some kind of library CLR integration but I'm not experienced in that...

**SQL**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(phoneNumber, '((([0-9])[ ()+-]*){10,11})([^0-9]|$)', '`\1¬','g'),
           '(^|¬)[^`¬]*(`|$)', ',', 'g'),
         '(^,|,$|[^0-9,])', '', 'g')
FROM tbl;
```

**Online Demo**

db-fiddle.uk demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b12d9f9779b686fd0c4aa84956595f70

**Explanation**

1. The innermost `REGEXP_REPLACE` locates groups of either 10 or 11 digits, each of which may have any number of space, bracket, plus or minus characters after it. The group must either be followed by a non-digit character or the end of the line. For each located group, a single `` ` `` is appended before the group of digits and a single `¬` is appended after. *You might need to adjust these characters to something rarer - they shouldn't appear anywhere else in the text.*
2. The middle `REGEXP_REPLACE` replaces each block of text that isn't between a pair of marker characters with a single comma.
3. The outermost `REGEXP_REPLACE` removes any commas at the start or end of the string and also removes anything that isn't a digit or comma.