# Replace string without fixed length

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data that I'm looking at that has text formatting stored within a `NTEXT` field.
Happy enough with SQL Replace to remove data of a known length and format, however there are some fields with what looks like colour formatting and I'm trying to find a way to remove these.

An example of the data below, however (if possible) I would like to be able to remove whatever numbers follow the colours in the data but can't see how to introduce a wildcard into the **replace** statement.
Something like `'\red***\green\***\blue***'` as per Excel, but this doesn't work in Sql Server.

```
declare @str varchar(1500) = '\red3\green73\blue125;Jimmy Jazz\red31\green73\blue125;'
select @str,
replace(@str,'\red31\green73\blue125;','')
```

Any pointers would be gratefully received, thanks in advance.

Comment: `ntext` is obsolete and will be removed from SQL Server.  I would suggest that you fix the database to use `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: True, however it's a third party school system and that change is scheduled for the next update.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data it would appear that you only need to remove the numbers in your string you can use [patreplace8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/patreplace8k) or using [patextract8K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60371071/2647342). Note the sample data and examples below:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @strings TABLE(stringId INT IDENTITY, string VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @strings VALUES('DeepPurple1978\yellow2\red009;pink\black3322'),
('red202\yellow5\red009;hotpink2'),('purple999\gray65\violet;blue\yellow381');

--==== Solution #1 Patreplace8k
SELECT
  s.stringId,
  pr.newString
FROM        @strings AS s
CROSS APPLY samd.patReplace8K(s.string,'[0-9]','') AS pr;

--==== Solution #2 PatExtract8k + STRING_AGG (SQL 2017+)
SELECT
  s.stringId,
  NewString = STRING_AGG(pe.Item,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pe.ItemNumber)
FROM        @strings AS s
CROSS APPLY samd.patExtract8K(s.string,'[0-9]') AS pe
GROUP BY    s.stringId;

--==== Solution #3 PatExtract8k + XML Concatination (Pre SQL 2017\)
SELECT 
  s.stringId,
  NewString = 
(
  SELECT      pe.item+''
  FROM        @strings AS s2
  CROSS APPLY samd.patExtract8K(s2.string,'[0-9]') AS pe
  WHERE       s.stringId = s2.stringid
  ORDER BY    pe.itemNumber
  FOR XML PATH('')
) 
FROM        @strings AS s
GROUP BY    s.stringId;
```

Each of these solutions return:

```
stringId    NewString
----------- -------------------------------------
1           DeepPurple\yellow\red;pink\black
2           red\yellow\red;hotpink
3           purple\gray\violet;blue\yellow
```

The second and third leverage concatenation, the second compatible with SQL Server 2017+ the third works with earlier versions (you did not include what version you are on.)

To only strip the numbers that follow one or more pre-defined colors you could use [patternsplitCM](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns). Note the use of a table with a group of colors your are seeking; in the real world I'd use a real table.

```
-- Colors
DECLARE @colors TABLE(color VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT  @colors VALUES('red'),('green'),('blue'),('yellow'),('purple'),('grey');

-- Sample data
DECLARE @strings TABLE(stringId INT IDENTITY, string VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @strings VALUES('Burger1978\yellow2\red009;pink\86thisfool'),
('red202\yellow5\red009;Freddy99'),('green999\grey65\violet;blue\yellow381');


SELECT 
  s.stringId, s.string, NewString = 
(
  SELECT
  (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(f.Item, IIF(f.M=0 AND EXISTS (SELECT c.Color FROM @colors AS c
                   WHERE c.Color = f.L),NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]',f.item),0),1),8000)
    FROM
    (
      SELECT ps.ItemNumber, ps.Item, ps.[Matched],
             LAG(ps.Item,1,ps.Item) OVER (ORDER BY ps.ItemNumber)
      FROM   dbo.PatternSplitCM(s.string,'[^0-9\ ;]') AS ps
    ) AS f(ItemNumber,Item,M,L)
    ORDER BY f.ItemNumber
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('(text())[1]','varchar(8000)')
)
FROM @strings AS s;
```

**Returns:**

```
stringId    string                                        NewString
----------- --------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
1           Burger1978\yellow2\red009;pink\86thisfool     Burger1978\yellow\red;pink\86thisfool
2           red202\yellow5\red009;Freddy99                red\yellow\red;Freddy99
3           green999\grey65\violet;blue\yellow381         green\grey\violet;blue\yellow
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, that looks useful. 
What I really want to do is replace the colours and numbers, but as the colour values range from 1 to 255, I need either 1,2 or 3 wildcards. 
I'll have a play with your solution though - might just have to remove the numbers, then the colours?