# Regex replace or LISTAGG on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, listagg

I need to "translate" this statement to SQL server

```
regexp_replace(Main.LOCK, '\/\/.*', '') TARGET
```

I need to get rid of this signs because before (or after, depends how you look) I use this one

```
LISTAGG(stock.LOCATION_NO, '//') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY isnull(QTY_OH,0)+isnull(QTY_TR,0) - isnull(QTY_RS, 0) desc) LOCK
```

Neither Regex and Listagg can be used within SQL server

What you see, what I'm trying to do (and it worked very well in Oracle) is to get the TARGET value that contains Main.LOCK with MAXIMUM value of

```
isnull(QTY_OH,0)+isnull(QTY_TR,0) - isnull(QTY_RS, 0)
```

Now I can't translate it properly to SQL server

Also, the error I've get are:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 12
> 'regexp_replace' is not a recognized built-in function name.
> Msg 10757, Level 15, State 1, Line 49
> The function 'LISTAGG' may not have a WITHIN GROUP clause.

Can anyone help here?

SQL Server ver 18.8

Warehouse Ver 13.0

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4583460) - 13.0.5103.6 (X64)
Nov  1 2020 00:13:28
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: _SQL Server ver 18.8_ ... that's probably the SQL Server Management Studio version. What's the actual version of SQL Server? Try exectuing `select @@version` to find out and [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67997688/edit) your question to include the result.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

The `regexp_replace()` is doing something pretty simple.  It is taking the portion of the string before `'//'`, if that is there.

In the more recent versions of SQL Server, you can use `string_agg()` and `left()`:

```
string_agg(left(main.lock,
                charindex('//', main.lock + '//')- 1
               ), '//'
          ) within group (order by coalesce(qty_oh, 0) + coalesce(qty_tr, 0) - coalesce(qty_rs, 0) desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has no built-in Regex functions but they are available via CLR. The good news is you don't need Regex in SQL Server. Everything I used to do with RegEx I now handle using [NGrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams). It's easy and performs much better. I've built a few functions using NGrams8K that would be helpful for this problem and many others. First we have [PatReplace8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/patreplace8k), second is Translate8K (updated code for both below.) A third option is [PatExtract8K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60371071/2647342) (follow the link for the code).

Examples of each performing the text transformation. With each function I'm just removing the Alpha characters and the numbers from 0-5 from "SomeString":

```
--==== Sample Data
DECLARE @table TABLE (SomeId INT IDENTITY, SomeString VARCHAR(40));
INSERT @table(SomeString) VALUES(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID()),(NEWID());

--==== Using Patreplace8k
SELECT      t.SomeString, f.NewString
FROM        @table                                         AS t
CROSS APPLY samd.patReplace8K(t.SomeString,'[0-5A-F-]','') AS f

--==== Using Translate8K
SELECT      t.SomeString, f.NewString
FROM        @table                                         AS t
CROSS APPLY samd.Translate8K(t.SomeString,'[012345ABCDEF-]','') AS f

--==== samd.patExtract8K
SELECT t.SomeString,
  NewString = STRING_AGG(f.item,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f.ItemNumber)
FROM        @table                                      AS t
CROSS APPLY samd.patExtract8K(t.SomeString,'[0-5A-F-]') AS f
GROUP BY    t.SomeString;
```

**Each Return:**

```
SomeString                               NewString
---------------------------------------- -----------------
0818BEF3-E0B3-4B3B-AA97-649E43EB16AF     8897696
3077EE8B-9E92-4337-9E2F-97DABE2E4623     7789979976
6BCD8194-F993-42DB-AF4A-D8289F8F8DA3     6899988988
C1F152DF-8B6F-4C14-AF6F-AC8869099FDB     866886999
F877D888-245E-4CEB-84B7-1CFF6E03B974     87788887697
```

To perform you string aggregation you can use XML PATH(), or STRING_AGG. Here's an example using both techniques and PatReplace8k:

```
SELECT NewString = STUFF((
  SELECT      '//'+NewString
  FROM        @table                                         AS t
  CROSS APPLY samd.patReplace8K(t.SomeString,'[0-5A-F-]','') AS f
  ORDER BY f.NewString
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'');

SELECT STRING_AGG(f.NewString,'//') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f.NewString)
FROM        @table                                         AS t
CROSS APPLY samd.patReplace8K(t.SomeString,'[0-5A-F-]','') AS f;
```

In each case I get what I want:

```
NewString
----------------------------------------------------
6967899797//777689886//868796//8887789//88989
```

**Translate Function:**

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION samd.Translate8K
(
  @string  VARCHAR(8000), -- Input
  @pattern VARCHAR(100),  -- characters to replace
  @key     VARCHAR(100)   -- replacement characters
)
/*
Purpose:
  Standard Translate function - the fastest UDF version in the game. Enjoy.
  For more about TRANSLATE see: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_translate.asp

Requires:
  NGrams8K; get you some here: 
    https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams

Designed By Alan Burstein; May, 2021
*/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT NewString = ISNULL(REPLACE(tx.NewString,CHAR(0),''),@string)
FROM
(
  SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(t.tKey+ng.Token AS CHAR(1)),'')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ng.Position)
  FROM        samd.ngrams8k(@string,1)               AS ng
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(@key+REPLICATE(CHAR(0),100)))  AS tx(NewKey)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(ng.Token,@pattern))) AS pos(N)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(tx.NewKey,pos.N,1))) AS t(tKey)
) AS tx(NewString);
```

**Patreplace8k:**

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [samd].[patReplace8K]
(
  @string  VARCHAR(8000),
  @pattern VARCHAR(50),
  @replace VARCHAR(20)
)
/*****************************************************************************************
[Purpose]:
 Given a string (@string), a pattern (@pattern), and a replacement character (@replace)
 patReplace8K will replace any character in @string that matches the @Pattern parameter 
 with the character, @replace.

[Author]:
 Alan Burstein

[Compatibility]:
  SQL Server 2008+

[Syntax]:
--===== Basic Syntax Example
 SELECT pr.NewString
 FROM   samd.patReplace8K(@String,@Pattern,@Replace) AS pr;

[Developer Notes]:
 1. @Pattern IS case sensitive but can be easily modified to make it case insensitive
 2. There is no need to include the "%" before and/or after your pattern since since we 
    are evaluating each character individually
 3. Certain special characters, such as "$" and "%" need to be escaped with a "/"
    like so: [/$/%]

 4. Functions that use samd.ngrams8k will see huge performance gains when the optimizer
    generates a parallel execution plan. One way to get a parallel query plan (if the
    optimizer does not choose one) is to use make_parallel by Adam Machanic found here:
 sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2013/07/11/next-level-parallel-plan-porcing.aspx

    As is the case with functions which leverage samd.ngrams or samd.ngrams8k, 
    samd.patReplace8K is almost always dramatically faster with a parallel execution
    plan. On my PC (8 logical CPU, 64GB RAM, SQL 2019) samd.patReplace8K is about 4X
    faster when executed using all 8 of my logical CPUs. 
 5. samd.patReplace8K is deterministic. For more about deterministic functions see:
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx


[Examples]:
--===== 1. Replace numeric characters with a "*"
 SELECT pr.NewString
 FROM  samd.patReplace8K('My phone number is 555-2211','[0-9]','*') AS pr;

--==== 2. Using againsts a table
 DECLARE @table TABLE(OldString varchar(60));
 INSERT  @table VALUES ('Call me at 555-222-6666'), ('phone number: (312)555-2323'),
                       ('He can be reached at 444.665.4466 on Monday.');

 SELECT      t.OldString, pr.NewString
 FROM        @table                                     AS t
 CROSS APPLY samd.patReplace8K(t.oldstring,'[0-9]','*') AS pr;

[Revision History]:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Rev 00 - 20141027 Initial Development - Alan Burstein
 Rev 01 - 20141029 - Redesigned based on the dbo.STRIP_NUM_EE by Eirikur Eiriksson
                    (see: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1585850-391-2.aspx)
        - change how the cte tally table is created 
        - put the include/exclude logic in a CASE statement instead of a WHERE clause
        - Added Latin1_General_BIN Colation
        - Add code to use the pattern as a parameter. - Alan Burstein
Rev 02  - 20141106 - Added final performance enhancement (more cudos to Eirikur Eiriksson)
                   - Put 0 = PATINDEX filter logic into the WHERE clause
Rev 03  - 20150516 - Updated to deal with special XML characters - Alan Burstein
Rev 04  - 20170320 - changed @replace from char(1) to varchar(1) for whitespace handling
                   - Alan Burstein
Rev 05  - 20200515 - Complete rewrite using samd.NGrams
                   - changed PATINDEX(...)=0 to: PATINDEX()&0x01=0;
                   - Changed CASE statement to IIF; Dropped collation - Alan Burstein
*****************************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT NewString = STRING_AGG(IIF(PATINDEX(@pattern,col.Token)&0x01=0,col.Token,
                   @replace),'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ng.position)
FROM        samd.NGrams8K(@string,1)                      AS ng
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ng.token)) AS col(Token);
```